# How to draw letters by dragging finger onScreen

Tags: android, touch

I am new to Android..Please anybody help me..I am working on application for kids..I want to make the user to draw above the text like A,B,C ..At the same time I want to make the user can only draw above the letters not outside of those letters..And while drawing I want to give the different colors..I have searched a lot but i didn't get exactly what I want..

Comment: this is a very complicated task..

Comment: Maybe it's not the kind of application that is best to start learning Android developpement ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Android I suggest you learn the basics first (web tutorials or books). If you are new to Java you should also have a look at this. Once you are starting to get the hang of both, you can move on to creating an application like this (which sounds tricky).

Just to get you started, I'd advice you to have a look at the `SurfaceView` class, which will allow you to render to the screen.

PS: Just a reminder, this site is for program specific questions, not vague questions. :)